# Facial Recognition

Tags: php, python, linux, macos

I'm on a mac but I also have a Ubuntu virtual machine so linux or Mac OSX solutions welcome.

I'm attempting to get facial recognition working.  The intention is to recognise a face from a database and bring up data about the individual.

On my mac I have attempted to install a few tools that claim to do this but havent managed to get any of them working.  I was hoping to use face.com but they are no longer accepting new users.

I've spent most of my time looking at python tools but anything that works is good with me now.  If anyone can suggest a tool and if possible link to installation and usage explanations it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where your **specific programming problem** is.

Comment: Have you tried OpenCV [FaceRecognizer](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OpenCV python interface.

http://opencv.org

But You will need a bit of effort to integrate data from a database too